# How does equivalence of categories preserve cartesian closedness?

Tags: category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

How does equivalence of categories preserve cartesian closedness?
Is it enough to show that equivalence of categories preserves terminal objects and binary products to show that it preserves finite products and then show all objects in the other category are exponentable?

Comment: Bud I don't know how to show that equivalence preserves exponentials...

Comment: Try using the hom-set definition of exponential objects, along with the fact that equivalences are fully faithful and preserve products. Those facts should be all you need.